# Unable to send string from one page to the other

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I got this code from Microsoft Virtual Academy which was supposed to help me pass a string from one page to the other.

The following is the code segment in C# on my destination page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
   string querystringvalue = ""; 
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out querystringvalue)) 
       Shopname.Text = querystringvalue;
}
```

However, when I tried using the code, it gave me an error on the void whereby it states:
"Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct"

It's really confusing because it's a code that Microsoft themselves provide and yet it shows up as an error on my IDE. @@

(Am running Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional to develop a Windows Phone App BTW)

Comment: The compiler should tell you exactly which line it is complaining about, and will probably provide additional error detail.  Please add that information to your question.

Comment: You should search for the error message "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct". Before posting here, you are expected to have done some research into the problem so that you can state why the existing solutions to the problem don't help: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @EricJ. The program underlined it right at the void and that was all they said lol.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've looked around, but there are not many on W8.1 or W8 phone app issues. And those that are present don't solve my problem T.T

Comment: @user3621999 The chances are that you've put that piece of code in the wrong place in the file. Maybe [General Structure of a C# Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2a9a9s3.aspx) will help you see where to put it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Okay, after moving the block of code here and there, I found the location where it stops giving errors. Am starting to confuse this with C++ @@
Thank you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a QueryString and assign it a value from the page you are trying to navigate from , So that when you navigate to another page , it can read the value you already store in a specific QueryString

Also when developing on Windows 8.1 or Windows phone , I recommend for you to use the Navigate Method in the control that you will use to navigate to the other page like that :

```
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MySecondPage), "SomeString");
```